# Advanced file browsers for output debugging

Tags: java, file, browser

Hi guys : I have a file system with lots of "parallel" data in it (details : its a local hadoop development environment).  In any case,

- I want a file browser tool that is pluggable, so that when I click on certain files, certain readers are invoked.
- I also want to compare parallel directories .  For example if I have a/ b/ and c/, each of which has output.txt, I want to compare the size/contents of output.txt across those directories.

Although I realize these are somewhat strange comparisons to do - I believe programmers probably do such comparisons quite often.  Does any generic tool exist for browsing large file/directory repos on disk ?

Hopefully, it would be java, and be java pluggable , but even a simple Mac OS X application might be useful to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

Kdiff3 has a great directory compare tool.

Answer (score 0):

For comparing files, the search term you are looking for is 'diff viewer'. Google immediately returns a link to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187064/graphical-diff-for-mac-os-x). There the recommended viewer is [FileMerge](http://osxdaily.com/2010/03/04/compare-two-files-with-filemerge/), although personnaly I prefer [Kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/), which seems to support OS X as well.